# numpy images - replace color based on other image

Tags: python, image, numpy

I'm trying to create image that shows the difference between 2 images. I have several functions that can compare 2 colors (array of 3 numbers) and returns how they differ 0.0 - 1.0.

```
compare_colors(color1, color2)
    # do some calculation
    return difference
```

Now I want to replace the pixels in the first image with constant color (let's say `[255, 0, 255]`) where the color difference is higher than defined `tolerance` using selected `compare_colors` function.

```
different = some selector where compare_colors(image1, image2) > tolerance
original_image[different] = [255, 0, 255]
```

However, I don't know how to create the selector with the `compare_colors` function. I also need to access individual color channels in `compare_colors` function.

Comment: Do you have a working `compare_colors`? If so, what's the output from it, as in the shape? Otherwise where are you stuck? Also - `" I also need to access individual color channels in compare_colors function."`- are you stuck with it? If so, that sounds like a basic problem. Could you narrow down your queries and state those in a concise/clear way? It sounds too broad for now.